# Is there a quick-starting Haskell interpreter suitable for scripting?

Tags: performance, scripting, haskell, interpreter

Does anyone know of a quick-starting Haskell interpreter that would be suitable for use in writing shell scripts?  Running 'hello world' using Hugs took 400ms on my old laptop and takes 300ms on my current Thinkpad X300.  That's too slow for instantaneous response.  Times with GHCi are similar.

Functional languages don't have to be slow: both Objective Caml and Moscow ML run hello world in 1ms or less.

**Clarification**: I am a heavy user of GHC and I know how to use GHCi.  I know all about compiling to get things fast.  Parsing costs should be completely irrelevant: if ML and OCaml can start 300x faster than GHCi, then there is room for improvement.

I am looking for

- The convenience of scripting: one source file, no binary code, same code runs on all platforms
- Performance comparable to other interpreters, including fast startup and execution for a simple program like

  ```
  module Main where
  main = print 33
  ```

I am *not* looking for compiled performance for more serious programs.  The whole point is to see if Haskell can be useful for scripting.

Comment: How often are you spawning new Haskell scripts? Is there something you can do about lessening that figure, first?

Comment: Not at all, except for testing.  My whole point is to be able to write scripts in something better then /bin/sh and more typechecked than Lua.
So I *want* to be doing it a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `ghc -e` is pretty much equivalent to invoking `ghci`.  I believe that GHC's `runhaskell` compiles the code to a temporary executable before running it, as opposed to interpreting it like `ghc -e`/`ghci`, but I'm not 100% certain.

```
$ time echo 'Hello, world!'
Hello, world!

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time ghc -e 'putStrLn "Hello, world!"'
Hello, world!

real    0m0.401s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.015s
$ echo 'main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"' > hw.hs
$ time runhaskell hw.hs
Hello, world!

real    0m0.335s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
$ time ghc --make hw
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hw.hs, hw.o )
Linking hw ...

real    0m0.855s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
$ time ./hw
Hello, world!

real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

How hard is it to simply compile all your "scripts" before running them?

#### Edit

Ah, providing binaries for multiple architectures is a pain indeed.  I've gone down that road before, and it's not much fun...

Sadly, I don't think it's possible to make any Haskell compiler's startup overhead any better.  The language's declarative nature means that it's necessary to read the entire program first even before trying to typecheck anything, nevermind execution, and then you either suffer the cost of strictness analysis or unnecessary laziness and thunking.

The popular 'scripting' languages (shell, Perl, Python, etc.) and the ML-based languages require only a single pass... well okay, ML requires a static typecheck pass and Perl has this amusing 5-pass scheme (with two of them running in reverse); either way, being procedural means that the compiler/interpreter has a lot easier of a job assembling the bits of the program together.

In short, I don't think it's possible to get much better than this.  I haven't tested to see if Hugs or GHCi has a faster startup, but any difference there is still faaar away from non-Haskell languages.

Comment: I use three different computing platforms: x86, amd64, and sparc.  The inconvience of compiling code for all three is significant.  I write a *lot* of scripts in Lua and `ksh`, and I'd rather use Haskell.  But not if I have to compile everything.

Comment: P.S. Your timings show my trouble exactly, except my 'echo' is a lot faster than yours... odd.

Comment: This was originally timed under Cygwin, where (because Windows is braindead) process creation is friggin' expensive.  Yeah, I don't see an easy solution to (lightweight + binary portable) Haskell "shell" scripts... sorry.

Answer (score 31):

Why not create a script front-end that compiles the script if it hasn't been before or if the compiled version is out of date.

Here's the basic idea, this code could be improved a lot--search the path rather then assuming everything's in the same directory, handle other file extensions better, etc. Also i'm pretty green at haskell coding (ghc-compiled-script.hs):

```
import Control.Monad
import System
import System.Directory
import System.IO
import System.Posix.Files
import System.Posix.Process
import System.Process

getMTime f = getFileStatus f >>= return . modificationTime

main = do
  scr : args <- getArgs
  let cscr = takeWhile (/= '.') scr

  scrExists <- doesFileExist scr
  cscrExists <- doesFileExist cscr
  compile <- if scrExists && cscrExists
               then do
                 scrMTime <- getMTime scr
                 cscrMTime <- getMTime cscr
                 return $ cscrMTime <= scrMTime
               else
                   return True

  when compile $ do
         r <- system $ "ghc --make " ++ scr
         case r of
           ExitFailure i -> do
                   hPutStrLn stderr $
                            "'ghc --make " ++ scr ++ "' failed: " ++ show i
                   exitFailure
           ExitSuccess -> return ()

  executeFile cscr False args Nothing
```

Now we can create scripts such as this (hs-echo.hs):

```
#! ghc-compiled-script

import Data.List
import System
import System.Environment

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  putStrLn $ foldl (++) "" $ intersperse " " args
```

And now running it:

```
$ time hs-echo.hs "Hello, world\!"     
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hs-echo.hs, hs-echo.o )
Linking hs-echo ...
Hello, world!
hs-echo.hs "Hello, world!"  0.83s user 0.21s system 97% cpu 1.062 total

$ time hs-echo.hs "Hello, world, again\!"
Hello, world, again!
hs-echo.hs "Hello, world, again!"  0.01s user 0.00s system 60% cpu 0.022 total
```

Comment: It's a really nice idea.  +1
It might not be too difficult to update it to deal with multiple architectures...

Comment: Absolutely a great idea. With a little work, this could very easily be a great tool, suitable for packaging on hackage.

Answer (score 5):

If you are really concerned with speed you are going to be hampered by re-parsing the code for every launch.  Haskell doesn't need to be run from an interpreter, compile it with [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) and you should get excellent performance.

Comment: Parsing costs are never completely irrelevant, and neither is the implicit richness of the expected runtime environment.  Maybe ML and OCaml have fewer 'load by default' libraries.  $ time python -c "print 33" is plenty fast!  And I have no doubt there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 4):

You have two parts to this question:

- you care about performance
- you want scripting

If you care about performance, the only serious option is GHC, which is very very fast: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=all

If you want something light for Unix scripting, I'd use GHCi. It is about 30x faster than Hugs, but also supports all the libraries on hackage.

So install GHC now (and get GHCi for free).

Comment: I don't care so much about overall performance as I do about *startup costs*.

Comment: "Very very fast"?  Let's not get carried away, Don---I've worked on GHC's back end, and I know where those particular bodies are buried :-)

Comment: Hey Norman. I really don't think there's much alternative to compiling scripts (if they run often), or using the #!/usr/bin/runhaskell syntax if they're run rarely.

Comment: That said, hugs starts up faster. It's just not very useful, imo.

Answer (score 3):

What about having a ghci daemon and a feeder script that takes the script path and location, communicates with the already running ghci process to load and execute the script in the proper directory and pipes the output back to the feeder script for stdout?

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to write something like this, but it seems like it could be really fast judging by the speed of :l in ghci. As it seems most of the cost in runhaskell is in starting up ghci, not parsing and running the script.

**Edit:** After some playing around, I found the [Hint package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) (a wrapper around the GHC API) to be of perfect use here. The following code will load the passed in module name (here assumed to be in the same directory) and will execute the main function. Now 'all' that's left is to make it a daemon, and have it accept scripts on a pipe or socket.

```
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
import Control.Monad

run = runInterpreter . test

test :: String -> Interpreter ()
test mname = 
  do
    loadModules [mname ++ ".hs"]
    setTopLevelModules [mname]
    res <- interpret "main" (as :: IO())
    liftIO res
```

**Edit2:** As far as stdout/err/in go, using [this specific GHC trick](http://nominolo.blogspot.com/2010/04/haskell-tip-redirect-stdout-in-haskell.html) It looks like it would be possible to redirect the std's of the client program into the feeder program, then into some named pipes (perhaps) that the daemon is connected to at all times, and then have the daemon's stdout back to another named pipe that the feeder program is listening to. Pseudo-example:

```
grep ... | feeder my_script.hs | xargs ...
            |   ^---------------- <
            V                      |
         named pipe -> daemon -> named pipe
```

Here the feeder would be a small compiled harness program to just redirect the std's into and then back out of the daemon and give the name and location of the script to the daemon.

Comment: Novel idea, but how do you bind input and output to the standard input, standard output, and standard error of the **client**?

Comment: Norman: I added some more ideas to address your question, but being a relative novice, I am out of my league here. Despite that, it seems rather straightforward given the linked blog post idea.