# Loading dynamic haskell module

Tags: reflection, dynamic, haskell

I'm looking for a way to load a Haskell function from a string to run.  I know the type before hand, but don't know the contents of the function.

Ideally, a solution would be quick and not need to run in IO.

I've been looking at hint (Language.Haskell.Interpreter), but it doesn't fit bill (eval calls show, modules must be in files).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712696/is-there-a-quick-starting-haskell-interpreter-suitable-for-scripting, but was unhelped

Comment: Are you asking for `eval` in one of the most static and safety-emphasizing languages around? How delightfully ironic...

Comment: Not necessarily.  A language that builds purity and sandboxing in seems like a great language for dynamic compiling.

Answer (score 3):

[`hint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) and [`plugins`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins) are the main options. `hint` lets you interpret functions as bytecode, `plugins` uses compiled object code.

Note that since these 'eval' functions must be type-checked prior to running them, they're rarely pure values, as evaluation may fail with a type error.

Comment: The hint uses Either types to encode errors, so it should be able to be pure.

Comment: Hint actually reloads the entire content of libraries in question and modules in scope.  That requires IO.

Answer (score -1):

The abstract answer is that you just have to make `(->)` an instance of [`Read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aRead) (and possibly [Show](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aShow) while you're at it)

How on earth you are supposed to do that, I don't know. It's no small task to interpret code.

If you are dealing with simple functions, the I would suggest creating an algebraic data type to represent them.

```
data Fun = Add | Subtract | Multiply deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

runFun Add      = (+)
runFun Subtract = (-)
runFun Multiply = (*)
```

---

```
*Main> runFun (read "Add") 2 3
5
*Main> runFun (read "Multiply") 2 3
6
*Main> runFun (read "Subtract") 2 3
-1
```